# Creating a dynamic web application

Tags: frameworks, dynamic

Consider a data registration application (register events, inspections etc.); how would one go about building it? You could define n-number of data fields, such as Date_Of_Event, Event_Description etc. OR one could build a dynamic application where there is metadata of some sort that defines what tables/columns are available.

My question is then: Are there any good examples of such implementations? Perhaps there are frameworks that can assist me in creating such an application?

FYI: I have been a developer on such an application previously and so I have a fair bit of knownledge on how it **can** be done, but I am looking at better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much dynamic is that. If the number of dynamic data fields is very big, then, of course, you may create or use some framework, but I would really consider looking into definition of more precise data model if it is possible. Generic approach is nice when you need some flexibilty, but if you need a lot of customization, then this dynamic field flexbility can bring a lot of painful maintenance comparing to a system with more strict data model.

**EDIT**: If you want to build some application based on some meta data model e.g. UML diagram, then you can look into some MDA tools like [AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/docs/index.html).

Comment: It would have to be a dynamic model, since we do not know ahead of time what fields a specific client would want.

Comment: We're not going to go down the 100% dynamic route, opting instead to go for "EXTRA_[datatype]_[numerator]" columns... Cost vs. Benefit. ;) Thanx for taking the time to respond.